# Update using loop in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

```
BEGIN
 FOR J IN (select DISTINCT  S_NUMBER from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO)
 LOOP
UPDATE wmwhse3.orders
SET
    orders.susr4 = (select S_NUMBER from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO where S_NUMBER = J)
where     orders.c_company = (select SHIPTO from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO where S_NUMBER = J)
and orders.orderkey in (SELECT  a.orderkey FROM wmwhse3.orders a INNER JOIN wmwhse3.wavedetail b ON a.orderkey = b.orderkey where b.wavekey = '0000000086');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can't use "FOR J IN (select DISTINCT S_NUMBER from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO) " I don't know why?

Comment: I can use FOR J IN 1...2  but I want replace with (select DISTINCT S_NUMBER from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO)

Comment: select DISTINCT S_NUMBER from WMWHSE3.NUMBER_SHIPTO
Result is
--------------------
S_NUMBER
--------------------
1
--------------------
2

Comment: You should use j.column_name while you are only using J. What is the error message you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're overcomplicating things (and making everything slower than it should be, as row-by-row processing (in a loop) is usually much slower than set processing).

Therefore, how about a single `update`, without PL/SQL? Something like this:

```
update orders o set
  o.susr4 = (select n.s_number
             from number_shipto n
             where n.shipto = o.c_company
            )
where exists (select null from wavedetail b
              where b.orderkey = o.orderkey
                and b.wavekey = '0000000086'
             );
```